# how can i keep/ save the user input in dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

words = {}

def add_word():
    ask = input("Do You Want To Add a New Word?(y/n): ")
    if ask == 'y':
        new_word = input("type the word you want to add: ")
        word_meaning = input("type the word meaning: ")
        words[new_word] = [word_meaning]

    elif ask == 'n':
        pass


add_word()

table = pd.DataFrame(data=words)
table_transposed = table.transpose()
print(table_transposed)
```

as you can see, i want to make a dictionary but i don't know how to save the user's input.
i want to take the user input and save it in the dictionary, so the next time he uses the program he can see everything he added before

Comment: It seems like you **did** add it to the dictionary. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179222/python-saving-data-outside-of-program ?

Comment: i think so but in my case what should i write,
i am sorry i am new to this

Comment: yeah i am adding it to the dictionary but it disappears when i run the program again.

Comment: Ok, of course. Whenever you run the program it has a new state. If you want to preserve state between runs, this is a duplicate question and has many answers already. Like the ones in the link I provided... More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201290/how-to-save-a-dictionary-to-a-file/32216025 ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100125/storing-python-dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make and populate (fill) a dictionary in a running Python program, that dictionary only exists as long as the program is running. When you close the program - that memory is wiped and any modifications that are made are not stored.

As Tomerikoo pointed out, this solution: [shelving dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17179282/13671374) will allow you to preserve your dictionary **after the program is closed**.
I copy the code from the link (jabaldonedo's solution) and annotate it for you for clarity.

```python
import shelve  # this is a Python library that allows you to store dictionaries after the program is closed
data = {'foo':'foo value'}  # this is a mock-up dictionary. "words" in your case
d = shelve.open('myfile.db')  # this creates a storage container in the program folder that can store multiple dictionaries. You can see this file appear when this code runs.
d['data'] = data  # you make a section in that storage container, give it a name, e.g. "data" in this case, and store your dictionary in that section. You will store your "words" here.
d.close() # close the storage container if you do not intend to put anything else inside.
```

When you close and open up the program, the dictionary will not automatically pop into your running memory - you need to write code to access it. It can be made as an option in your game menu, e.g. "Load existing dictionary of words".

Back to jabaldonedo's solution:

```
import shelve  # no need to import again, if you are writing in the same python program, this is for demonstration
d = shelve.open('myfile.db')  # open the storage container where you put the dictionary
data = d['data']  # pull out the section, where you stored the dictionary and save it into a dictionary variable in the running program. You can now use it normally.
d.close() # close the storage container if you do not intend to use it for now.
```

**EDIT:** Here is how this could be used in the specific context provided in your answer. Note that I imported an additional library and changed the flags in your `shelve` access commands.

As I mentioned in my comment, you should first attempt to load the dictionary before writing new things into it:

```
import shelve
import dbm  # this import is necessary to handle the custom exception when shelve tries to load a missing file as "read"


def save_dict(dict_to_be_saved):  # your original function, parameter renamed to not shadow outer scope
    with shelve.open('shelve2.db', 'c') as s:  # Don't think you needed WriteBack, "c" flag used to create dictionary
        s['Dict'] = dict_to_be_saved  # just as you had it


def load_dict():  # loading dictionary
    try:  # file might not exist when we try to open it
        with shelve.open('shelve2.db', 'r') as s:  # the "r" flag used to only read the dictionary
            my_saved_dict = s['Dict']  # load and assign to a variable
            return my_saved_dict  # give the contents of the dictionary back to the program
    except dbm.error:  # if the file is not there to load, this error happens, so we suppress it...
        print("Could not find a saved dictionary, returning a blank one.")
        return {}  # ... and return an empty dictionary instead


words = load_dict()  # first we attempt to load previous dictionary, or make a blank one

ask = input('Do you want to add a new word?(y/n): ') 
if ask == 'y':
    new_word = input('what is the new word?: ')
    word_meaning = input('what does the word mean?: ')
    words[new_word] = word_meaning
    save_dict(words)
elif ask == 'n':
    print(words)  # You can see that the dictionary is preserved between runs
    print("Oh well, nothing else to do here then.")
```

Comment: tanks a lot for your help, i understood a lot about shelve and i tried a couple of examples, but i am not sure about how can i use it in my code, because of the above function i am confused.

Comment: Make a function that will take in your dictionary as parameter. This function, let's say you call it `save_dict`, will save the dictionary using the `shelve` library as I outlined in the first code box. Make a second function that will load the dictionary, call it `load_dict`, it will use the second code box snippet to load the dictionary. You can then let the user choose which function to run.

Comment: i added a new answer because i couldn't write the code here, can you please solve the problem i mentioned

Answer (score 1):

```
import shelve
words = {}
def save_dict(words):
    s = shelve.open('shelve2.db', writeback=True)
    s['Dict'] = words
    s.sync()
    s.close()


def load_dict():
    s = shelve.open('shelve2.db', writeback=True)
    dict = s['Dict']
    print(dict)
    s.close()


ask = input('Do you want to add a new word?(y/n): ')
if ask == 'y':
    new_word = input('what is the new word?: ')
    word_meaning = input('what does the word mean?: ')
    words[new_word] = word_meaning
    save_dict(words)
elif ask == 'n':
    load_dict()
```

so this is my code after making the save_dict and load_dict functions, it works fine but when i run the program and write a new_word and word_meaning it overwrites the previous data, i believe i am missing something in the save_dict function, if you can point the problem to me i would be so grateful

Comment: Good job so far. Your mistake is easy to understand. Say you run the program for the first time and add 10 words. The 10-word dictionary gets saved. Next time you run the program you immediately decide to add 5 words. The 5-word dictionary gets saved and overwrites your previous dictionary... Solution? Load the words dictionary before you make additions to it. Also, in your `load_dict()` you should return the `dict` that you load and store it in `words`, as in, that way you will actually load and use the dictionary you saved before.

Comment: i understood your point but i couldn't apply it, if you can tell me what code should i write and where, that will actually help me a lot, because i will understand better if i could see the program running correctly, i tried so many times, but this shelve library is driving me crazy, i am having problems to understand it, thank you and i am sorry if i am wasting your time.

Comment: I updated my answer with an adapted version of your code.

Comment: thank you so much, i tried it and it finally worked